"Invalid signature v value" shown when contract is deployed on MyEtherWallet using Ganache
I am developing my own smart contract using myEtherWallet.com, ganache and solidity. Here is my code:
catcoins_ico.sol:
//Version of compiler
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract catcoin_ico{
    // Introducing the max number of Catcoins available for sale
    uint public max_catcoins = 1000000;

    // Introducing US Dollar to Catcoin conversion rate
    uint public usd_to_catcoin = 1000;

    // Introducing total number of Catcoin that have been bought by the investors
    uint public total_catcoins_bought = 0;

    // Mapping the investor address to its equity in Catcoins and USD
    mapping (address => uint) equity_catcoins;
    mapping (address => uint) equity_usd; 

    // Checking if an investor can buy catcoins (If there is enough catcoins left)
    modifier can_buy_catcoins(uint usd_invested){
        require(usd_invested * usd_to_catcoin + total_catcoins_bought <= max_catcoins);
        _; //This underscore says that the function to which we will link the modifier wll only be appeard
            //if the condition is true.
    }

    // Getting the equity in Catcoins of an investor
    function equity_in_catcoins(address investor) external returns (uint) {
        return equity_catcoins[investor];
    }

    // Getting the equity in USD of an investor
    function equity_in_usd(address investor) external returns (uint) {
        return equity_usd[investor];
    }

    //Buying Catcoins
    function buy_catcoins (address investor, uint usd_invested) external 
    can_buy_catcoins(usd_invested){
        uint catcoins_bought = usd_invested * usd_to_catcoin;
        equity_catcoins[investor] += catcoins_bought;
        equity_usd[investor] = equity_catcoins[investor] / usd_to_catcoin;
        total_catcoins_bought += catcoins_bought;
    }
     

     // Selling Catcoins
     function sell_catcoins (address investor, uint catcoins_sold) external {
        equity_catcoins[investor] -= catcoins_sold;
        equity_usd[investor] = equity_catcoins[investor] / usd_to_catcoin;
        total_catcoins_bought -= catcoins_sold;
    }
}

I have created a custom node on MyEtherWallet and perfectly input http link and port no in it. After that I went to 'contracts' and then 'Deploy Contract'. Then clicked 'compile catcoin_ico.sol' and then I copied 'bytecode' and paste it on Byte Code section in MyEtherWallet. Then put Gas Limit 30000 manually. After that I clicked sign transaction and then deploy contract. But error message "Invalid signature v value" is shown. What is the issue here?
I tried to change gas limit but nothing is changing here.
